# Can I use column value in MySQL WHERE INTERVAL select

Tags: mysql, timestamp, where-clause

I have a system that checks websites for certain data at set frequencies. Each website has its own check frequency in the `crawl_frequency` column. This value is in days.

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `websites` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `domain` VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `crawl_frequency` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '3',
    `last_crawled_start` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I want to run queries to find new websites to check at their specified check frequency/interval. At the moment I have this query which works fine if the `crawl_frequency` for a website is set to one day.

```
SELECT domain
FROM websites
WHERE last_crawled_start <= (now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
LIMIT 1
```

Is there any way in a MySQL query I can use the value that is in the `crawl_frequency` column for each row in the `WHERE` clause.

So example I'd like to do something like:

```
SELECT domain
FROM websites
WHERE last_crawled_start <= (now() - INTERVAL {{INSERT VALUE OF CRAWL FREQUENCY FOR THIS PARTICULAR WEBSITE}} DAY)
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
SELECT domain
FROM websites
WHERE last_crawled_start <= NOW() - INTERVAL crawl_frequency DAY
LIMIT 1
```

Yes, really.

Comment: ha that's embarrassing!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `DATEDIFF` function, like this:

```
SELECT domain FROM websites
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), last_crawled_start) > crawl_frequency
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I suggested datediff first but then i remembered it's not very accurate for this. It only returns ints, and i believe it essentially returns the number of midnight transitions between 2 dates, so if your website was crawled at 23:59 on the first and its now 00:01 on the third, datediff returns 2 even though only 1.01 days have passed - it could mean it's crawled again too soon

Answer (score 1):

Everything i read for mysql said it can't be variable, but you can use another function e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM websites 
WHERE 
  (unix_timestamp() - unix_timestamp(last_crawled_start))/86400.0 > crawl_frequency
```